# Optimizations for LM2596, Positive and Negative Voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, texas-instruments, buck-boost

I'm working with the LM2596 to get a positive and negative voltage using two separate IC for each. I'm having trouble optimizing them for a 1 A load. I followed along with TI's WEBBENCH designer to optimize them resulting in the circuit below, but I was wondering if some adjustments can be made for a smoother output voltage with lower ripple? The parameters include a 10-20V input range, with an output of 5 V, 2.5 A. I found the adjustable model in LTspice, and I'm using that to simulate the results, but it seems I'm getting around 2% ripple voltage at the output even though my design is supposed to get 0.02%.

Regarding the negative output circuit, TI's webbench didn't allow for a negative output using the LM2596. I followed the negative output example as best as I could to get the output voltage that I wanted, but are there any suggested optimizations I should take for the design, or is it fine as it is?

EDIT: Sorry, wanted to note. The input voltage is taken from a rectifier, so it's a positive, rectified, unregulated DC voltage.

EDIT: Wanted to add more information. Regarding the negative voltage circuit, when I ran it with a 1 amp load as shown below, the input voltage oscillates between 6 to 8.4 V. According to the datasheet, the input should take from 4 to 20 V, but is this okay given how my negative output is -9.5 volts? Does this limit the current output by the circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftwrfx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: *"my design is supposed to get 0.02%"* Is that according the webbench? Did uo take the same parasitic values into account?

Comment: @Huisman Do you mean parasitic values of the other components? No, I didn't.

Comment: Yes, inductors eg have a default parasitic series resistance in LTspice, and iirc Webbench uses the ESR of capacitors where LTspice caps have 0 ESR by default.

Comment: @Huisman I took into account the ESRs and the IRMS of the caps and inductors in LTspice, basing it from the chosen components in Webbench as best as I could. Webbench worked for the positive output, but the negative output was based on the proposed circuit in the datasheet. Only thing I didn't adjust are the LC ripple filter pairs at the end: L4/C9 and L2/C4